# What is a simple & common command line tool to show network usage on a Linux machine?

Tags: linux

I'm looking for a simple command line linux tool that will show me the current network usage, the same way *top* displays CPU usage.

What is the most standard tool (I can't install new things on the server) that will do the task. I don't need anything fancy and a simple text based tool will do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i like [ifstat](http://gael.roualland.free.fr/ifstat/):

```
brzoza:~# ifstat -b 1
       eth0                eth1                eth2       
 Kbps in  Kbps out   Kbps in  Kbps out   Kbps in  Kbps out
 7870.11  27165.49  24776.69   7626.12      0.00      0.00
 8738.48  27760.18  26787.02   7851.60      0.00      0.00
 8532.13  28028.55  26122.37   7850.08      0.00      0.00
 9029.12  25981.44  23108.86   8282.37      0.00      0.00
```

but there is much more - iptraf, iftop, nload just to name the few.

if you cannot really install / compile anything new - you'll have to write simple script parsing the output of ifconfig and calculating incements for input/output counters. two examples i've found: [here](http://blog.kagesenshi.org/2006/03/bandwidth-monitoring-script-through.html) and [here](http://meinit.nl/shell-script-measure-network-throughput-linux-machines).

Answer (score 3):

Here are two tools that are worth checking out, although they are probably not available by default on your distribution :

- [nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/) : a simple tool that will display the network usage by process :

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/nethogs.png))</sub>

- [tcptrack](http://www.rhythm.cx/~steve/devel/tcptrack/) is also very good, especially on a gateway - you can get the bandwidth used by any IP adress coming in or out your server :

[image]
<sub>(source: [steve at www.rhythm.cx](http://www.rhythm.cx/~steve/devel/tcptrack/ss_113.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

On top of what pQd has mentioned, one of my favourites is `pktstat` instead. I often used that.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite so far is [ifstatus](http://ifstatus.sourceforge.net/graphic/screenshots.html). It is curses based so it works in a terminal and it gives a graph of your traffic history over time (fully configurable).

Answer (score 0):

`ntop` might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

List open conncetions

```
lsof -i :80
```

List all services called httpd

```
lsof -i -nP | grep httpd
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `nload` that does not require root privileges for a simple view of bandwidth usage

[nload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PY7H.png)

You can use `iftop` that require root privileges in order to understand the connection in/out from your network card (use SHIFT+S for a more complete view)

[iftop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjYyE.png)

***You can compile the software with a stanrdard gcc.***

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault! It will be a lot easier for people to follow your answers if you include terminal output as text and not as pictures. If you mark the text and press the `{}` button, it will be formatted as "code", so that all spaces, line breaks etc will be included.

Comment: The tool is a terminal-gui application, I've upload the image Sir